# Calculating Average Treatment Effect

Tags: statistics

According to Gerber & Green (2012, p. 25), the Average Treatment Effect (ATE) can be expressed by  $ATE=1/N*\Sigma_{i=1}^{N}Y_i(1)-1/N*\Sigma_{i=1}^{N}Y_i(0)$ but also $1/N*\Sigma^N_{i=1}(Y_i(1)-Y_i(0))$.

Suppose these values:

| Y | d |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 1 |
| 15 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 15 | 0 |
| 30 | 1 |

The ATE can easily be calculated as such using the first formula: $ATE = 1/2*(15+30)-$1/5*(15+20+20+10+15)=22.5-16=6.5

My question is: How do I calculate this value using the second formula? Can someone show me the steps? Intuitively, I would believe that because we iterate through 1 to 7, it should look like this: $1/7*(15+15+20+20+10+15+30)$, but obviously this is wrong. How can I fill it in when we only ever observe either d = 1 or d = 0 for one individual?

I hope this question from an absolute non-expert in math and mathematical expressions make sense.

*Source: Gerber, A. S. & Green, D. P. (2012). Field experiments: Design, analysis, and interpretation. WW Norton.*